# Graphing Sleep Data Android Wear - What Library

Tags: wear-os

I'm working on an Android Wear project that writes sleep data from sensors to files.

Next I want to interpret the data on the watch and make each Sleep Log visual.

I usually make web apps and I would use HighCharts or D3 to do this.

What libraries can I use on Android Wear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Google Fit to [track sleep data](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/releases).

> Developers can now read and write granular sleep data. This includes
>   light sleep, deep sleep, REM, and awake activities. These granular
>   activity types have been added to the FitnessActivities enumerated
>   type.

-To insert sleep data, create a session of type FitnessActivities.SLEEP.

To detect granularity in your session, insert activity segments of types:

-FitnessActivities.SLEEP_LIGHT

-FitnessActivities.SLEEP_DEEP

-FitnessActivities.SLEEP_REM

-FitnessActivities.SLEEP_AWAKE

You can also check the Android Wear sample for Google Fit in this [github repo](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WatchFace).